# Display Form Validation Error Using mkString()

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to display error messages into my view by using the in built mkString method call on my form. However the result is not as expected:

i have:

```
    @productForm("name").errors().mkString(", ")
```

and the view renders the following:

```
    ValidationError(name,error.required,[])
```

How can i display the exact message?

I am using play 2.1.1 (it is a java project)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`@productForm("name").errors()` returns a collection of `ValidationError` objects. You want to run `mkString` on a collection of validation error messages, so you need to first map your `ValidationError` collection of to a collection of Strings:

```
@productForm("name").errors().map(n => n.message).mkString(",")
```

I think this will now return you `error.required`, which is still not quite what you want. So when you map you'll probably want to map to a Messages API lookup:

```
@productForm("name").errors().map(n => Messages(n.message)).mkString(",")
```

Comment: perfect! this works. Although slight modification which is the get() method applied to the Messages: `@productForm("name").errors().map(n => Messages.get((n.message)).mkString(","))`

Answer (score 0):

if you want the error for the field name than use the error not errors

```
@productForm.error("name").message
```

if you need the parameters of the error for example the max length or whatever you can use

```
@productForm.error("name").arguments()
```

Comment: `@productForm.error("name").message` would return the key, so in my example this would be `error.name.required` - hence this would need to be mapped to the value. Which can be achieved like: `@Messages.get(productForm.error("name").message)`